# who is this VS. who this is

Tags: word-order, clauses, inversion, emphasis, content-clauses

> I don't know who **this is**
>
> I don't know who **is this**

Though I know the first one is more acceptable, especially grammatically, eventually, I want to raise the following question:

We could use the second one in *especial* situation, that is:

When we are going to emphasis the **who**, so we use the second one, if so, would you show me it in a vivd way?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Thank you for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of any circumstance when the second form would be valid. That reversed construction is used only in interrogative: 
"Who is this?"

Comment: Nevertheless, I am sure the second one exists. But, I am not able to explain it in English. A native might explain.

Comment: I was born in Seattle,and live in California; I am a 14th-generation American. What kind of native are you looking for?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, I've heard it in African-American Vernacular English and AAVE-influenced chants, rap, etc. Nima, while I would accept AAVE as an acceptable dialect of spoken English, it is not accepted as grammatical written. "Who this is?" is not a grammatical English sentence. Nor is there any particular change in emphasis in this phrasing. Please try to find a non-AAVE reference.